# Trying to use classes in JS

Tags: javascript, class, object, destructuring

I'm new to using classes and I'm trying to figure out how to get info to display in the browser. I've made a JS class (Vehicle) and I'm trying to use it to display info in the browser using de-structuring of an object. I can't figure out what I did wrong here, because I get nothing in the browser, yet no errors pop up when I inspect the page elements. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Here's the HTML:

```
<body>
<div id="displays">
</div>

    <script src="vehicle.js">

        let car = new Vehicle("black", 137, 127, 208);

        document.getElementById('displays').innerHTML = car.show();

    </script>


</body>
```

And here's the JS:

```
class Vehicle{
    constructor(color, direction, currentSpeed, topSpeed, engineStarted){
        this._color = color;
        this._direction = direction;
        this._currentSpeed = currentSpeed;
        this._topSpeed = topSpeed;
        this._engineStarted = true;
        this.active = true;
    }

    show() {

            if(this._active)
            {
                const stats = `${this._color} car, Top Speed: ${this._topSpeed} mph, Current Speed: ${this._currentSpeed} mph, ${this._direction}`;
                return stats; 
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Script elements can *either* have a `src` or text content. They cannot do both. So if you want to use your vehicle using inline script on the page, put that in a second `<script>` element. Although it's better to put that in its own file, say `index.js` and then have that second `<script>` element have a `src="index.js" defer` instead:

```html
<body>
  <div id="displays"></div>
  <script src="vehicle.js" async defer>
  <script src="indexjs" async defer>
</body>
```

using the modern `async` and `defer` attributes to make sure the scripts are loaded without blocking, and execute after the DOM has been constructed, but just before `DOMContentLoaded` gets signalled.